# Why don't partials work in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

```
  myModule.search location, item, (err, data) ->
    if err?
      res.end 'Error!'
    else
      res.write 'got here'
      partial 'partials/table', {items: data, layout: false}
      res.end()
    return
```

I get the following error on my server:

```
        partial('partials/table', {
        ^
ReferenceError: partial is not defined
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's `res.partial` not `partial`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the examples in the [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) demonstrate it as a global function, I think it's only actually available like this within a view:

```
#data-view
  != partial('datalist', { collection: data })
```

You can find a number of examples of this under [`/examples/partials`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/partials) in the repository.

Within your script, however, it's a method of the response object:

```
res.partial 'partials/table', {items: data, layout: false}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that it changed a little. You need to investigate extends ../layout, block content and include.

Search for the examples in:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/jade

Answer (score 0):

Partials are no longer available for 3.0+ Express JS version. So you have to check out for includes that contains the same conception.